# How to detect password protected word, excel file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, ms-word, ms-office

My application will search ms office document such as word, excel, etc in folder and then read the tag in metadata.

But my function will hang/stop when the function try to open a password protected (need password) file.

How can I detect the file had been password protected? If yes, I skip this file and proceed on next file.

```
'Read Word metadata
Public Sub ReadWord(WordFileName As String)

    Dim Wapp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    Dim docWord As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document

    If Wapp Is Nothing Then
        Wapp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    End If

    If docWord Is Nothing Then
        docWord = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
    Else
        docWord.Close()
    End If

    docWord = Wapp.Documents.Open(WordFileName)

    Dim _BuiltInProperties As Object = docWord.BuiltInDocumentProperties

    If Not _BuiltInProperties Is Nothing Then

        word_keyword = _BuiltInProperties("Keywords").Value

    End If

    If Not docWord Is Nothing Then
        docWord.Close()
    End If

    If Not Wapp Is Nothing Then
        Wapp.Quit()
    End If

End Sub

'Read Excel metadata
Public Sub ReadExcel(ExcelFileName As String)

    Dim Wapp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim excelbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook

    If Wapp Is Nothing Then
        Wapp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    End If

    excelbook = Wapp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFileName)

    Dim _BuiltInProperties As Object = excelbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties

    If Not _BuiltInProperties Is Nothing Then
        excel_keyword = _BuiltInProperties("Keywords").Value
    End If

    If Not excelbook Is Nothing Then
        excelbook.Close()
    End If

    If Not Wapp Is Nothing Then
        Wapp.Quit()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That's not a "write protected Excel file", it's a **password protected Excel file**. There's a very big difference. AFAIK, you can't tell it's password protected until you try to open it.

Comment: It looks like you can check the `Workbook.HasPassword` property for Excel files. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1946295/138938    Word has a `Document.HasPassword` property. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.haspassword(v=vs.100).aspx