# How to Skip Opening of Password Protected Excel Files (win32com, python)?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I have a bunch of Excel files which I am opening automatically using `win32com` to copy some data. 
Some of the files are password protected, which causes a password pop-up window appear at opening these. So i have to either type a password or click the 'Cancel' button manually. 
I don't know the password and I don't need to open them - I just want to skip these protected files (it doesn't matter if I skip them before this popup occurs or after it occurs - as long as it skips automatically).

The setup for my Excel application is:

```py
import win32com.client as w32cl
excelapp = None
result_wb = None
curr_wb = None
excelapp = w32cl.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
excelapp.DisplayAlerts = False 
excelapp.ScreenUpdating = False 
excelapp.AutomationSecurity = 3
```

I am opening each file with something like this:

```py
try:
    curr_wb = None
    curr_wb = excelapp.Workbooks.Open(FileName = 'some_filename.xlsm', UpdateLinks = 0)
except Exception as exc:
    pass
```

The password pop-up stucks the code on line with `Open()`, waiting for my input, and by pressing 'Cancel' code resumes with an exception which I catch.

So, is there a way to know if Excel file is protected before opening or is there a way to automatically skip this pop-up once it appeared or (maybe) auto-cancel this pop-up?

I'm using Python 3.7 (Anaconda) and MS Office 365.

UPD: the trick with an empty password seemed to work, but not exactly.

I have 3 password protected files in a test list.
If I try to open them like this,

```py
curr_wb = excelapp.Workbooks.Open('some_file.xlsx', UpdateLinks = 0, ReadOnly = True, CorruptLoad = 2, Password = '')
```

each of them throws me an exception about the wrong password, which is fine.

But when I try to open them **without** `CorruptLoad=2`, then the *first* protected file in the list make the password dialog show up, and each of the *next* protected files is throwing the exception like it should.

I can't use `CorruptLoad=2` everytime because it loses Excel formula calculations in normal files. I have to call `Open()` with `CorruptLoad=2` second time if file is corrupted - so this *first* file password dialog stil appears at normal opening, but just once.

What can be the problem here? 
I've already tried to clear the `pycache` and regenerate COM Excel code via `EnsureDispatch()` and relaunching, and this weirdness still exists.

Comment: I'd just try to figure out a robust Python method to figure out whether an `xls?` file is password-protected. The file formats are documented, after all, and encryption would be one of the first things in a file header.

Comment: In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59761333/2064588 the user says you can pass a blank password and try catch the error. If the workbook has password, you will land in the catch. I can't test it tho

Comment: @FrancescoGiossi I've already tried to pass an obvoiusly wrong passwords, and I've just tried to pass an empty one and even `None` - no dice. I mean it is still popping up the password window.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on your `excelapp.Workbooks.Open` issue but there is another option for checking if an Excel file is password protected.
This uses the `msoffcrypto` module which can return the password protection status as `True` or `False` using the `is_encrypted()` attribute. 
But it has to check the file first. Then you open the file in win32com or not based on the returned state.
If you're not able to sort the other method this might be your option.

```
import win32com.client as w32cl
import msoffcrypto  # pip install msoffcrypto-tool

result_wb = None
curr_wb = None
excelapp = w32cl.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
excelapp.DisplayAlerts = False
excelapp.ScreenUpdating = False
excelapp.AutomationSecurity = 3


file = '<full path>\Book1.xlsx'

with open(file, 'rb') as file:
    protected_file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(file).is_encrypted()  # Returns True or False

if not protected_file:
    curr_wb = excelapp.Workbooks.Open(file, UpdateLinks=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just got back to this problem, and in my case your solution is inapplicable - package requires Python >= 3.8 as stated here https://pypi.org/project/msoffcrypto-tool/#description.

Comment: Given 3.7 is EOL and there have been no other options presented it may be time to make it applicable :)